# Prove or Disprove the following Conjecture

Tags: number-theory

There are infinitely many prime numbers expressible in the form $n^3+1$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

I am not sure whether this is true or not. I tried to prove that it is true via contradition:

Assume via contradiction that there are finite number of prime numbers that can be written in the form $n^3+1$  where $n$ is a positive integer. Then there exists an $N$ such that $N^3+1=P_N$ , where $P_N$ is a prime number and for all $n\ge N$, $n^3+1$ is composite. My idea was to create another prime number greater than $N$ that can be written in this form potentially $(2N)^3+1$ to produce a contradiction. But I am not sure how to construct such a prime number.Can anyone provide hints as to how to approach this problem? I would appreciate hints more than answers.

Comment: Hint: $n^3+1 = (n+1)(n^2-n+1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$n^3 + 1 = (n+1)(n^2-n+1)$$

Comment: If I am understanding correctly $n^3+1=(n+1)(n^2-n+1)$ since this is prime then either $n+1=1$ or $(n^2-n+1)=1$. Note $n+1\neq 1$ since this implies $n=0$ not a positive number and $n^3+1=1$ not a prime so $(n^2-n+1)=1$ which implies $(n-1)=0$ resulting $n=1$ so the only prime that can be written in this form is 2. So the conjecture is false.

Comment: Great stuff, indeed!